# How to make multiple sections in home pulling posts category wise?

Tags: posts, query-posts, categories

This question may look foolish to everyone or novice , but i am working on a theme . It will be basically a news publishing theme .

Right now , In my home page all posts are showing one after another like a usual WordPress theme.

No extra coding has been implemented on the theme .

But i want to make different sections on the home page and naming each section as its

category's title and pulling the posts from that category and show them in that section .

Like other news related themes do by making blocks in their home page and showing posts like " breaking news " , " hot right now " etc

I hope you have got the point that i am saying .

I have read about custom post types and wp_query posts but i dont have the code exactly i want for this .

Any kind of help will be very much appreciated

Gratis

Comment: how are the categories selected? automatic from the site? from theme options?

Comment: from theme option actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run a foreach loop through all your categories then run a query for the latest posts in each category.  You can do this by setting your home page to a static page then put this in a custom template.  This is just a basic example:

```
$categories = get_the_categories();
    foreach ( $categories as $cat ) {

    $exclude = isset( $GLOBALS['current_id'] ) ? $GLOBALS['current_id'] : null;
    $args = array(
         'cat' => $cat->term_id,
         'posts_per_page' => 4,
         'post__not_in' => array( $exclude ),
         'no_found_rows' => true,
          );

     echo '<h3>'. $cat->name . '</h3>';
     $home_q = new WP_Query( $args );
     while ( $home_q->have_posts() ) : $home_q->the_post();
     $GLOBALS['current_id'] = get_the_ID();

     // Do loop stuff here......

     endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();

    }
```

The `$GLOBALS['current_id']` will hold an array of post ids to use in each additional query to prevent a post from showing up more than 1 time if it's in multiple categories.  Setting 'no_found_rows` to true will make the query less taxing by not getting all the posts for pagination and stuff.

Comment: hey Chris_O , can i get the id from the option panel? i am using theming option framework .